# Getting rid of a blank line but keeping others intact

Tags: php, regex

After deleting an entry from a file, am left with a blank line where the entry used to be, and would like to know how to get rid of it at the same time of script execution.

My data.txt file has the following entries:

```
1
12
123 (line to be deleted)
1234
(blank line, carriage return)
```

plus an empty line at the bottom of the line which I would like to keep but not the one left after an entry has been deleted.

what I'm left after entry has been deleted:

```
1
12

1234
(blank line, which I want to keep intact)
```

Here is my present working code below:

```
$bodycont = preg_replace("/\b({$_POST['inscripnum1']})\b/","",$index);
```

How can I implement something on the same line to delete the line that the number was on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: Watch out, passing unfiltered user input into a regex can allow for a limited set of exploits, including minor denial of service attacks.  Take a look at [`preg_quote`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Comment: @Charles: I can understand injection attacks, but why DOS attacks?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik, depending on the version of PCRE and the version of PHP, it's possible to construct a regex that will consume a great deal of CPU time.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor My expected result was to delete the empty line after an entry has been deleted. Have a look at my original post, where I showed the blank line that was left in my file, after it was deleted.

Comment: @Charles I have to say (admit) that I am far from being a programmer. I can modify code to a certain extent, so I don't know how to deal with potential risks. I appreciate the info though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the line break in the regex:

```
$bodycont = preg_replace("/\b({$_POST['inscripnum1']})\b\n/","",$index);
```